# What does the endpoint.pose() command mean in the Baxter SDK

Tags: ros, baxter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the Baxter SDK there is a command  endpoint_pose() when I execute it with the a specified limb I get a reuslt like

{'position': Point(x=0.14484562211109325, y=0.6912815563308439, z=-0.45768906596768155), 'orientation': Quaternion(x=-0.5946265621165651, y=0.8034360301238139, z=0.029333852671252516, w=-0.007022977415755815)}

Does anyone know what this result  mean.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258790/what-does-the-endpoint.pose()-command-mean-in-the-baxter-sdk/) by [Glass_Eater](https://answers.ros.org/users/29913/glass_eater/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2017-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This function returns the pose of the limb's endpoint with respect to the `/base` frame. I believe that the endpoint is considered to be the `<left|right>_gripper` frame. The "position" key is the position of the endpoint frame, and the "orientation" key is the orientation expressed as a quaternion. This is described here:

http://api.rethinkrobotics.com/baxter_interface/html/baxter_interface.limb.Limb-class.html#endpoint_pose

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2017-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Glass_Eater](https://answers.ros.org/users/29913/glass_eater/) on 2017-04-07**:
@jarvisschultz thank you for your answer I also want to ask if you know what the difference between the position and orientation is.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2017-04-08**:
The position represents the location in x-y-z Cartesian coordinates of the gripper frame relative to the base frame. The orientation represents the rotations that exist between the gripper frame and the base frame. This could be expressed many ways (Euler angles, SO(3), or quaternions)

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2017-04-08**:
Quaternions are a convenient way of describing rotations. They are used often in ROS (and many other areas)